# Confused about how to combine CONV1D and LSTM

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, lstm, tf.keras

I am struggling to understand this code which combines both `CONV1D` and `LSTM`.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5,
                      strides=1, padding="causal",
                      activation="relu",
                      input_shape=[None, 1]),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu"),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * 400)
])

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, None, 32)          192       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, None, 64)          24832     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, None, 64)          33024     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, None, 30)          1950      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, None, 10)          310       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, None, 1)           11        
_________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)              (None, None, 1)           0         
=================================================================
Total params: 60,319
Trainable params: 60,319
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

If we remove the `CONV1D` layer and the second `LSTM` layer i am perfectly fine. However, i am deeply confused about this structure.

First, why are we adding `return_sequences=True` in the second `LSTM` layer? Usually we only add `return_sequences=True` at the first `LSTM` layer in case of a `stacked LSTM`. In this model, we are adding it to both.

Second, why is the `input_shape=[None, 1]` in `CONV1D` layer?  isn't `CONV1D` and `LSTM` somewhat similar in shape?

```
Conv1D: (batch, length, channels)
LSTM: (batch, timeSteps, features)
```

Much appreciate it if you can share a link that explains how to combine both models.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your output to be a sequence, for instance if you want to predict the 10 next values, the last `return_sequences` should be `True`. If you have 10 time steps in your data, it will return a sequence of 10 time steps. E.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5,
                      strides=1, padding="causal",
                      activation="relu",
                      input_shape=[None, 1]),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu"),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * 400)
])

model(np.random.rand(1, 10, 1))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 0.12037009],
        [ 0.19570792],
        [ 0.3986496 ],
        [ 0.56172705],
        [-0.06423644],
        [-0.4780491 ],
        [-0.82960564],
        [-1.2271142 ],
        [-1.8704925 ],
        [-2.294954  ]]], dtype=float32)>
```

I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for the answer. I understand what you mean. But my question is how is it possible that we can combine the `return_sequences=True` with a `dense` layer? We usually do it with `return_sequences=False`. Regarding my second question, i don't understand the `input_shape` of the `CONV1D` layer.

Answer (score 1):

This code is using `sequence-to-sequence` forecasting and not `sequence-to-vector` as explained in this video (link below). That is the reason we put `return_sequences=True` in both `LSTM` layers.

https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud187/lessons/6d543d5c-6b18-4ecf-9f0f-3fd034acd2cc/concepts/c10fb954-25ea-43e3-b22c-21b3e423eb05

This is a great course for time series `forecasting` using `neural networks`